# .NET Core MultiTenancy causing Area routing in ajax to not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, multi-tenant

I am using the Finbuckle Multitenant Library and I have encountered an issue with routing to Areas in my Views when I try to do ajax calls.

```
private static void ConfigRoutes(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IRouteBuilder routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute("Login", "Login", new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", area="Identity"});
    routes.MapRoute("Default", "{__tenant__=}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute("AreaGeneric", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute("Area", "{__tenant__=}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
}
```

These are the routeMaps that a defined in my Startup.cs

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Preview", "Account",new { area="Identity"})",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#user-container").empty();
                var url = "@Url.Action("Index","Manage",new { area="Identity"})";
                $("#user-container").append($('<a href="' + url+'"><h5>Welcome, ' + result.UserDetails.FirstName + " " + result.UserDetails.LastName +'</h5></a>'));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the ajax script that is having the issue. The url always reads as

> https://localhost:44311/TenantOne/Account/Preview?area=Identity

instead of

> https://localhost:44311/TenantOne/Identity/Account/Preview

What can I do to solve this? I'm not sure that I missed anything in my routing.

Comment: I think you need place the `routes.MapRoute("Area", "{__tenant__=}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");` as the first route. `IRouter` based routes are matched one by one in sequence.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. That works! However, when I login now, instead of going to https://localhost:44311/TenantOne, it goes to https://localhost:44311/TenantOne/Identity instead. I've removed the second route.MapRoute but its still happening.

Comment: Does that login page reside in the `Identity` area?

Comment: Yes. But it shows that I have successfully logged in if I remove Identity from the URL

Comment: I thought it was an expected behavoir? if you want to omit the `identity` `area`, you should not use the  pattern `{area:exists}` since it requires the `area` must exist. Try adding a default value for it.

Comment: I added area=Area as an example but its still showing up as Identity. I'm not sure where this is coming from.

Comment: Try `{area=Identity}`

Comment: Oh! It worked! How did it work?

Comment: That's because when generating the url link, the default value within the routes will be omitted if the provided values equal the default one.