# Anchor tag helper not generating correct route to area

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm afraid that I am at the end of my tether and cannot find a solution. I have exhausted my Google-fu abilities and am now having to ask for help. I'm afraid I am a novice and that this may be simple, this is for a small project I am using to learn.

To cut to the chase. I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with MVC controllers using endpoints. I want to add my areas seperately to the endpoint routing in the startup.cs. I have TagHelpers setup in my _ViewImports and other views are working.

**The issue:** in my book editor which has a paginatedlist the links are missing the area `Dashboard/` and if I put `asp-area="Dashboard"` into the `<a></a>` form links when I interact with them I get this URL generated:

> https://localhost:5001/LibraryTomes/TomeLanguageEditor?tomelanguid=dd0186f7-2ff4-46d1-b69c-3eaae0f91331&page=2&area=Dashboard

so instead of having:

> https://localhost:5001/Dashboard/LibraryTomes/TomeLanguageEditor?tomelanguid=dd0186f7-2ff4-46d1-b69c-3eaae0f91331&page=2

I am getting the area appended `&area=Dashboard`. I have found a few articles however, they all appear to only fix the issue with {area:exists} which I don't want.

The following is my Startup.cs under `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>` I believe this to be correct as I wanted to move away from the pattern of `area:exists`.

```
namespace TestProject
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940

        public class UntrustedCertClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
        {
            public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
            {
                return new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true
                };
            }
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            FlurlHttp.ConfigureClient("https://127.0.0.1", cli => cli.Settings.HttpClientFactory = new UntrustedCertClientFactory()); //Ignore test certs

            var settingsfile = File.ReadAllText(@"settings.json");
            var deserialjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsJson>(settingsfile);

            if (deserialjson.DatabaseProvider == DBProviderWrittenSetJson.MSSQL)
            {
                var connection = Configuration[@"MSSQLDBConnection"];
                services.AddDbContext<TestProjectContext>
                    (options => options.UseSqlServer(connection,
                    x => x.EnableRetryOnFailure())
                    );
                services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TestProjectContext>();
            }
            if (deserialjson.DatabaseProvider == DBProviderWrittenSetJson.PostgreSQL)
            {
                var connection = Configuration[@"PostgreSQLConnection"];
                services.AddDbContext<TestProjectContext>
                    (options => options.UseNpgsql(connection,
                    x => x.EnableRetryOnFailure())
                    );
                services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TestProjectContext>();
            }           

            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, TestProjectContext context)
        {
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            var settingsfile = File.ReadAllText(@"settings.json");
            var deserialjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsJson>(settingsfile);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                    {
                        endpoints.MapControllers();
                        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();

                        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                            name: "default",
                            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                        endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                            name: "Dashboard",
                            areaName: "Dashboard",
                            pattern: "{area=Dashboard}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
                            defaults: new { area = "Dashboard", controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

                    });

        }
    }
}
```

I have been trying a lot of things with routes and tried using HttpGet.

```
namespace TestProject.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers
{
    [Area("Dashboard")]
    [Route("Dashboard/LibraryTomes")]
    public class LibraryTomesController : Controller
    {

        //[HttpGet("TomeLanguageEditor")]
        [Route("TomeLanguageEditor", Name = "TomeLanguageEditor")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TomeLanguageEditor(string? tomelanguid, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, LibraryViewModel? libraryViewModel, int? page)
```

I will create a simple demo of what I am seeing, so more to come!

Comment: I guess this question is somehow similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59153320/net-core-multitenancy-causing-area-routing-in-ajax-to-not-work). However, since you didn't show us the code of Startup, I'm not totally sure about that. But if that approach doesn't work for you, could you please show us the complete code of startup? It would be awesome if there's a minimal demo that reproduces the same issue.

Comment: @itminus That helped! I then moved my area route above the default and my BookEditor page is now working without issue.

Thanks very much for your help!